# Argument 1 has unexpected type 'numpy.int64

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I use a traffic simulator to read the OSM road section ids and add lanes to particular sections based on ids. The following code reads all the section ids and adds lanes.

```
sectionType = model.getType( 'GKSection' )

for types in model.getCatalog().getUsedSubTypesFromType( sectionType ):

 for section in types.values():
 a = int(section.getId())
 print(a)
 s = model.getCatalog().find( a )
 s_lane = GKSectionLane() 
 section.addLane( s_lane, 0 )
```

Next, I store all the sections ids in a dataframe, and merge it with another dataframe to get the required section ids to add lanes based on designs. Then I iterate over the rows of merged dataframe to add lanes to sections using the following code.

```
#ExternalD display from map
import pandas as pd
data = []
sectionType = model.getType( "GKSection" )
for types in model.getCatalog().getUsedSubTypesFromType( sectionType ):
 for s in types.values():
    data.append([s.getId(),s.getExternalId(),s.getName()])
    df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns =['Section','Eid','name'])
 print(df)

df2 = pd.read_csv (r"C:\\Users\\Downloads\\Test1.csv")
#print (df2)
data_partial = pd.DataFrame( df2, columns=['Section','name','Design_options'])
#print( data_partial )
Data = data_partial.loc[data_partial['Design_options'] == 'Design C']
#print ( Data )
commondf = pd.merge( df, Data, on=['Section'] )
#print(commondf)



for index in range(len(commondf)):
     a = (commondf.iloc[index, 0])
     #print (a)

s = model.getCatalog().find( a )
s_lane = GKSectionLane()
section.addLane( s_lane, -1 )
```

I got the error "Python Error (<class 'TypeError'>): GKCatalog.find(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'numpy.int64'"

Comment: A stack trace would be very useful

Comment: If you cast `a` to an int does it work? I.e. `s = model.getCatalog().find( int(a) )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the error message, I'm guessing that `commondf` is an `int64` array, which means that although you think that `a` is an integer, it is in fact a special numpy type that looks and prints like an integer, but isn't.

Use `a.item()` to convert it into its native Python type--in this case an integer.